# Differentiate insert and update while set event in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

How to differentiate insert or update?

```
from sqlalchemy import event

@event.listens_for(SomeClass.some_attribute, 'set')
def receive_set(target, value, oldvalue, initiator):
    # Some logic..
    # Here i need to verify target is created or being updated.
    # Based on update/insert I have to set different value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the documentation on [object states](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/session.html?highlight=insert%20update#quickie-intro-to-object-states).

The persistent state is what you are concerned about.  If it is false, an insert should take place, otherwise an update.

```
from sqlalchemy import event, inspect

@event.listens_for(SomeClass.some_attribute, 'set')
def receive_set(target, value, oldvalue, initiator):
    if inspect(target).persistent:
        # update here
    else:
        # create here
```